# Trying to use an Image Array in Angular but there in a problem with my *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

Hello I am trying to get this array to be able to iterate through, I am not asking to solve the whole problem but in line 8 of my HTML, where the NgFor is there is an error where it cannot find the name. Any insight would be appreciated. 
Here's my code:
HTML:

```
<div class="row mw-100 mh-100 ">
<div class="col-3 .d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
<button mat-button-raised
(click)='current.id - 1'
class='button LeftClick'>Left</button>
</div>

<div class='col-6 .d-flex justify-content-center text-center Images'>
<img *ngFor="let current of Images"
  [src]='current'>
<br> {{current.name | uppercase}}
</div>

<div class="col-3 .d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
<button mat-button-raised
(click)='current.id + 1'
class='button RightClick'>Right</button>
</div>

</div>
```

TS File:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageMock } from './image';
import { ImageList } from './image.list';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

Images = ImageList;
current: ImageMock;

ngOnInit() {
  }
  constructor() {}

}
```

image.list:

```
import { ImageMock } from './image';


export const ImageList: ImageMock[] = [
   {post: '/assets/pics/0.png', id: 0, name: 'Ring'},
   {post: '/assets/pics/1.png', id: 1, name: 'Monkey'},
   {post: '/assets/pics/2.png', id: 2, name: 'Sehurio'},
   {post: '/assets/pics/3.png', id: 3, name: 'Mare'},
   {post: '/assets/pics/4.png', id: 4, name: 'Sehi'},
   {post: '/assets/pics/5.png', id: 5, name: 'Saturn'}, ];
```

image:

```
export class ImageMock {
  post: string;
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

As you can see I have created a service image.list which has been Imported from that I created the array where the images are under ImageMock. 
Also I have got my Images to show up using the NgFor to cycle through the array but have not yet been able to show only one image.

Thank you again any advice is appreciated!

Comment: What's the data structure of ImageMock and ImageList? Can you share sample data?

Comment: I think having a class member named current and then declaring a new variable of the same name in the ngFor is going to cause some issues.

Comment: You are assigning `ImageList` type to the `Images` variable and not the object. Try doing `new ImageList()` for a start but even then, i can't tell you more since you haven't provided the code for `ImageList`.

Comment: Thank you for comments, I just updated the code to include the other imported files. @MarioŠkrlec

Comment: @DanOswalt I see what you are saying by declaring the variable that I am using, I have been changing that around but still hasn't resulted in showing an image. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure from your question what you are trying to do, 
but it sounds like you are currently able to show all of the images (using the *ngFor),
but would like to show just one image at a time, with the buttons navigating backwards and forwards in the list.

Assuming that is indeed what you are trying to do, then you should not use *ngFor, since *ngFor will repeat the  tag, once for each item in the list.

What you need to do instead is to keep track of the current index in your component, and increment or decrement it according to the button clicks. Then just have a single  tag where the 'src' attribute is the url of the item in the list with the current index.

If you have trouble with that, create a stackblitz example with whatever you have, and ask another question here, linking to the example, and explaining simply, completely, and clearly, what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try that. was not using *NgFor before and was able to display an image but only the one selected, eg current.post[0] showing the first image.